# Tools for dns lookup in ubuntu

Tags: dns

I've updated A record in a domain config panel, panel shows me updated domain config bu site still is on old hosting. Where can I check all records for domain?

Comment: What panel software are you using? What operating system and version is your server running on?

Answer (score 7):

Not knowning the addresses of the dns servers, the best place to check is google:

```
dig whatiaminterestedin @8.8.8.8
```

Do notice that updates can easily take 24 hours or more. It's not common, but it happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dig](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/host.1.html), or any other online tool for [dns lookup](https://domain-records-lookup.com). Both will show you whats going on with your domain config.